# Creating an animation for composite images in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am loading a set of images and I have a corresponding 'rectangular patch' that I want to add on each of the images. I want to play them as a sequential animation.

```py
frames = np.load('../data/carseq.npy') #frames
bbox = np.load('carseqrects.npy')  #bounding boxes

final_=[]
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)
for i in range(num_frames):
    box = bbox[i]
    final_.append([plt.imshow(frames[:,:,i], cmap='Greys_r',animated=True)])
    final_.append([ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((box[0],box[1]),height+1,width+1, linewidth=2, 
                  edgecolor='red',fill=False))])

ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, final_, interval=100, blit=True,
                                repeat_delay=1000)

plt.show()
```

I get what is fundamentally wrong with this code,

```
final_.append([ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((box[0],box[1]),height+1,width+1, linewidth=2, 
                  edgecolor='red',fill=False))])
```

is just adding a white plot with a red rectangle on it, so the rectangle gets drawn after the previous frame is cleared - and this creates a 'flashing' effect (since the rectangle isn't exactly drawn on the frame itself). Is there any other way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

The list of artists passed to `ArtistAnimation` can be a list of lists, where each "row" of the list contains all the artists that need to be drawn on the current frame.

```
frames = np.load('../data/carseq.npy') #frames
bbox = np.load('carseqrects.npy')  #bounding boxes

final_=[]
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)
for i in range(num_frames):
    cur_frame = []
    box = bbox[i]
    cur_frame.append(ax.imshow(frames[:,:,i], cmap='Greys_r',animated=True))
    cur_frame.append(ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((box[0],box[1]),height+1,width+1, linewidth=2, 
                  edgecolor='red',fill=False)))
    final_.append(cur_frame)

ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, final_, interval=100, blit=True,
                                repeat_delay=1000)

plt.show()
```